# CVE-2021-44228 + slf4j + common-logging

Tags: log4j, slf4j, apache-commons-logging, cve-2021-44228

I am using slf4j in my project with the following :

```
implementation "org.slf4j:slf4j-api:${versions.slf4japi}"  (1.7.32)
implementation "org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:${versions.slf4jsimple}"  (1.7.32)
```

I am really confused because I don't have the log4j-1.2.17.jar in my project but in common-logging I have this dependency :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.17</version>
  <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

I am aware that they made a [statement](http://slf4j.org/log4shell.html) and I am nearly kind of sure that my project is concerned and I don't know how I can fix it ! Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, as mentioned in the SLF4J post you have linked, Log4j 1 is not affected by CVE-2021-44228 (but is end of life and affected by other vulnerabilities). Additionally it is marked as *optional* dependency so by default not included when you depend on common-logging, see the [POM Reference](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependencies) and [Introduction to the Dependency Mechanism](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies), which mentions this as well:

> It may be helpful to think of optional dependencies as "excluded by default."